# Cannot translate a working CURL PUT statement into a functioning python script

Tags: python, curl

Here is the working curl statement that I am trying to put into a python script:

```
curl -L -H 'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key: <key>' -X PUT -H'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"name":"new SSID name", "enabled":true, "authMode":"psk", "encryptionMode":"wpa", "psk":"abcd1234", "ipAssignmentMode":"Bridge mode"}' 'https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/[networkId]/ssids/[number]'
```

Here is my python code.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/XXXXXXX/ssids/2"
headers = {'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': 'YYYYYYY', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
payload = {"name":"test", "enabled":"true", "authMode":"psk", "encryptionMode":"wpa", "psk":"abcd1234", "ipAssignmentMode":"NAT mode"}

r = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=payload, allow_redirects=True)

print r.status_code
```

When I run the curl command, it works, but when I try the python script, I get a 400 error message.  My guess is that it has to do with the way that the application is interpreting the payload.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
data=json.dumps(payload)
```

Instead of:

```
data=payload
```

When you add `'content-type': 'application/json'` header, you mean that you're sending a `json data`, that's why you need to use `json.dumps()` to sent a valide json data instead of a `Python dictionary / object`.

Comment: That was it!! Thank you for your help.